# GCM after unregister still receive notifications

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

I am using GCM. Its work perfect but after unregister i still receive notifications.

This is my registration:

```
     // Make sure the device has the proper dependencies.
    GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(context);

    // Make sure the manifest was properly set - comment out this line
    // while developing the app, then uncomment it when it's ready.
    GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(context);

    registerReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter(
            DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION));

    // Get GCM registration id
    final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(context);

    // Check if regid already presents
    if (regId.equals("")) {
        // Registration is not present, register now with GCM           
        GCMRegistrar.register(context, SENDER_ID);
    } else {
        // Device is already registered on GCM
        if (GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(context)) {
            // Skips registration.              
            Toast.makeText(context, "Already registered with GCM", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            // Try to register again, but not in the UI thread.
            // It's also necessary to cancel the thread onDestroy(),
            // hence the use of AsyncTask instead of a raw thread.

            mRegisterTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    // Register on our server
                    // On server creates a new user
                    ServerUtilities.register(context, user, pass, regId);
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                    mRegisterTask = null;
                }

            };
            mRegisterTask.execute(null, null, null);
        }
    }`
```

And from different activity i am trying to unregister from GCM:

```
GCMRegistrar.unregister(getApplicationContext());
    GCMRegistrar.onDestroy(getApplicationContext());
```

And after that i still receive notifications :(

Comment: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html

Comment: Unregistration may take up to 5 minutes to propagate.

Answer (score 0):

First, `GCMRegistrar` is deprecated.

Second, `unregister()` indicates that this device should never again receive messages. Frequently registering and unregistering is not expected app behavior. If you want to stop receiving messages, *tell your app server to stop sending them*.